# Android Application sub-class constructor not being called

Tags: android, constructor, android-manifest

I have a class in my Android application that sub-classes the AndroidApplication object.  The documents say:

> public void onCreate ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Called when the
>   application is starting, before any
>   other application objects have been
>   created. Implementations should be as
>   quick as possible (for example using
>   lazy initialization of state) since
>   the time spent in this function
>   directly impacts the performance of
>   starting the first activity, service,
>   or receiver in a process. If you
>   override this method, be sure to
>
> call super.onCreate().

I placed a breakpoint on my sub-class's constructor and when I run my application, it is never reached.  Naturally, when I call the sub-class's getInstance() method from other code it returns NULL since the instance variable is (supposed to be) initialized when the constructor is called.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?  I would assume from the docs that I don't have to create an instance of the AndroidApplication sub-class myself, or do I?  Am I supposed to modify my manifest file somehow to add the AndroidApplication sub-class and if so, how?

-- roschler

Comment: Could you show yor code?

Comment: Also have you declared your Application class in Manifest?

Answer (score 7):

I'm posting the answer here for others.  Yes you need to add the name of your Application object sub-class's name to the Android manifest.  For Eclipse users, the easiest way to do this is to open the AndroidManifest.xml file, select the Application tab in the manifest editor, and use the Browse button next to the **Name** field to find your Android Application object sub-class name and select it.  The manifest file will be updated properly to register it.  I just did that and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a million! Thanks to this I noticed that I accidentaly put name="MyApp" instead of **android:** name="MyApp" in the manifest, and I was wondering why my constructor was never called...

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem of not having a . before my application class name.
Should be:
android:name=".MyApp"

since the MyApp class is in the package defined in the manifest.